# Yii2 Dependant drop down not working when we open update page

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii2

Yii2 Dependant drop down not working when we open update page.My depend drop down value came from database. When I create entry It works Very well with the condition. but I when go for Update then Pre selectect value does not show. i.e. Which I save while creating. This is my _form.php

```
        $arrCountry =  \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($modelCountry, 'country_id', 'country');

        echo $form->field($model, 'country_id')->dropDownList($arrCountry, 
             ['prompt'=>'-Choose a country-',
              'onchange'=>'
                $.post( "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('country/lists?id=').'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                  $( "select#city_name" ).html( data );
                });
            ']); 
       $dataPost=\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(City::find()->asArray()->all(), 'city_id', 'city_name');
      // print_r($dataPost);die;
       echo $form->field($model, 'city_id')
       ->dropDownList(
            $dataPost,           
            ['id'=>'city_name']
        );
```

2.Controller

```
public function actionLists($id)
    {
        $countCity =City::find()
                ->where(['city_id' => $id,'status'=>'not assign'])
                ->count();

        $arrCity = City::find()
                ->where(['city_id' => $id,'status'=>'not assign'])
                ->orderBy('city_id DESC')
                ->all();

        if($countCity>0){
            foreach($arrCity as $arrCity){
                echo "<option value='".$arrCity->city_id."'>".$arrCity->city_name."</option>";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "<option>-</option>";
        }

    }
```

Comment: I just refrred that that example for depedant drop downlist. In that example they retunr like this.

Comment: It returns count of not assign city

Comment: ok. but what is solution?for update

Comment: I manage this because for update.if record is not new then show this part if(!$model->isNewRecord){  and else{ is for to create

Comment: yes... i just tried this

Comment: my problem is same as http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/56912-setting-dependent-dropdown-values-during-update/

Comment: when i remove that code. the problem not solved. next solution please

Comment: okay.... no problem

Comment: Do you have solution for it

Comment: You need to create function ex. name it `cityList($country_id)` which return city list based on country then put `actionLists()` code inside that function. Call `cityList()` in both `_form` and `actionLists()`.

Comment: We need the update action codes from your controller to figure out the problem.